# Shir Shel Yom - Wednesday

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms

The Shir Shel Yom of Wednesday is unique that it includes besides the whole chapter of Tehilim 94, the first 3 verses of Tehilim 95. All the other days it includes just a complete chapter.

Does anyone discuss this? Why were these three additional verses added on?

Comment: The Shir Shel Yom is in fact just chapter 94.

Comment: I heard that it includes the first lines of lechu neranena because it signifies the earliest that one could start Shabbat. Or something like that.